# watir: How do I enter a value in a form, without submitting the form with watir?

Tags: watir

I have a simple login form that has 2 text fields and a button.
I can set the text of the username field just fine.
When I set the password field however, the form automatically submits, and I get an error.

From IRB:

```
irb(main):008:0> ie.text_field(:name, "j_password").set("password")
WIN32OLERuntimeError: unknown property or method `value'
    HRESULT error code:0x80070005
      Access is denied.
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/watir.rb:3431:in `method_missing'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/watir.rb:3431:in `doKeyPress'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/watir.rb:3427:in `each'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/watir.rb:3427:in `doKeyPress'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/watir.rb:3393:in `set'
        from (irb):8
irb(main):009:0> ie.text_fields.each {|x| puts x }
type:         text
id:
name:         j_username
value:
disabled:     false
length:       20
read only:    false
type:         password
id:
name:         j_password
value:
disabled:     false
length:       20
read only:    false
```

Any ideas why the error, or why the form is being submitted?

Note: I can set the fields just fine without the form being submitted using perl, vbscript, python, autoit, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could tell you more if you posted relevant HTML or link (if page is public), but my guess is that entering password fires JavaScript event that submits the form. `Access is denied.` could mean that there is a frame, and IE does not allow access to it (http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Frames).

Maybe this would help:

```
ie.text_field(:name, "j_password").value=("password")
```

Comment: Works great!
There is no javascript to submit the form on entering the password, but there some that fires on a specific letter combination that I was un-aware of. The actual string that I was passing just happened to contain it. Thanks again.